# Rails Adding Extra JSON to Requests

Tags: json, ruby, ajax, http, ruby-on-rails-4

I've noticed the following type of entry in my Rails log:

```
Parameters: {"notes"=>"test", "name"=>"AAAA", "city"=>"city",  "country"=>"country", "label"=>{"name"=>"AAAA", "city"=>"city", "country"=>"country", "notes"=>"test"}}
Unpermitted parameter: label
```

I've written two different clients that send JSON to my Rails API app running on Apache. One is Angular/Dart and the other is Cocoa Swift for MacOS. Both only send the first part of the JSON (i.e., up to "label"=>). I even see it on a select all request when I don't send any JSON data (e.g.,{"label"=>{}}). The extra data doesn't cause any problem other than the warning. Any idea on how to get rid of the duplicate JSON? I know how to get rid of the warning.

My Swift code that builds the request:

```
    let url = domain + rest
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

I don't add ".json" to the end of the request.

rake routes:

```
         labels GET    /labels(.:format)                    labels#index
                POST   /labels(.:format)                    labels#create
          label GET    /labels/:id(.:format)                labels#show
                PATCH  /labels/:id(.:format)                labels#update
                PUT    /labels/:id(.:format)                labels#update
                DELETE /labels/:id(.:format)                labels#destroy
```

One of my controllers:

```
class LabelsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @label = Label.new(label_params)
    if @label.save
      render :json => @label
    else
      render json: @label.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  ...
  private

  def label_params
    params.permit(:name, :city, :country, :notes)
  end
end
```

Comment: I think it is related to strong parameters, how are you sanitizing the params on your controller?

Answer (score 0):

This is a rails strong parameters error. You need to tell your controller that you expect to receive the label param.

Something like this in your controller:

```
def person_params
  params.require(:foo).permit(:label)
end
```

If you comment with your controller code I can give you a more specific answer.

Comment: I sorry I wasn't more clear about the question. I want to get rid of the duplicate JSON data. I've been looking at my log a lot lately and I want it to be cleaner.